# Spring application running in docker container is not reachable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-container

I've built a spring-boot application. I create a docker image with the following docker file:

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN microdnf install findutils
RUN ./gradlew build
COPY build/libs/*.jar app.jar

FROM openjdk:17
COPY --from=builder /app/app.jar .
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

I run the application together with a Postgres database

### docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.8"

services:    
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
    expose:
      - "1999"
    ports:
      - "1999:1999"
    command: -p 1999

  api:
    image: api
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker

networks:
  default:
```

This works perfectly on windows, but as soon as I move this to my linux (Zorin OS) machine, I'm not able to reach the application on `localhost:8080`, even though the application in the container is active.

#### docker container logs

```
[main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2381 ms
[main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
[main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.5.Final
[main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead
[ main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
[main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@9ec531
[main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
[main] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
[main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
[main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
[main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@54755dd9, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@f1f7db2, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@4d3c6593, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@590adb41, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@633cc6b5, com.voidhub.api.configuration.jwt.JwtUsernameAndPasswordAuthenticationFilter@4462efe1, com.voidhub.api.configuration.jwt.JwtTokenVerifier@7c3e4b1a, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@516462cc, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3456558, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2db4ad1, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@43bf5397, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@68ed3f30, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@28ee7bee]
[main] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Thymeleaf configuration, or set spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=false)
[main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
[main] com.voidhub.api.ApiApplication           : Started ApiApplication in 7.341 seconds (process running for 7.904)
```

#### docker ps

```
d1e2d34d8dbd   api   "java -jar /app.jar"     6 seconds ago   Up 5 seconds          0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp                                                                 voidhub-backend-1
251065ab7afa   postgres                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago     Up 5 seconds          0.0.0.0:1999->1999/tcp, :::1999->1999/tcp, 5432/tcp                                                       postgres
```

running `curl localhost:8080` results in

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

however, running `netstat -aon | grep 8080` results in

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Connection Reset to a Docker container usually indicates that you've defined a port mapping for the container that does not point to an application.

Did you define `server.address=localhost` in your `application.properties`?
If so, try to remove it or replace it with `0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i did something wrong regarding docker networking. this is what the new compose file looks like

```
services:    
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    network-mode: host
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
    expose:
      - "1999"
    ports:
      - "1999:1999"
    command: -p 1999

  api:
    image: api
    network-mode: host
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
```

notice how i added a network mode to both services.